# ZF3 Unit test authentication onBootstrap

Tags: php, authentication, phpunit, zend-framework3

I have a problem getting a unit test to run for my `IndexController` class.

The unit test just does the following (inspired from the [unit-test tutorial of zf3](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/unit-testing/#your-first-controller-test)):

`IndexControllerTest.php`:

```
public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->dispatch('/', 'GET');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    $this->assertModuleName('main');
    $this->assertControllerName(IndexController::class); // as specified in router's controller name alias
    $this->assertControllerClass('IndexController');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('main');
}
```

In the `Module.php` I've some functionality to check if there is a user logged in, else he will be redirected to a `login` route.

`Module.php`:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    /** @var AuthService $authService */
    $authService = $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(AuthService::class);
    $this->auth = $authService->getAuth(); // returns the Zend AuthenticationService object

    // store user and role in global viewmodel
    if ($this->auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $curUser = $this->auth->getIdentity();
        $mvcEvent->getViewModel()->setVariable('curUser', $curUser['system_name']);
        $mvcEvent->getViewModel()->setVariable('role', $curUser['role']);
        $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, [$this, 'checkPermission']);
    } else {
        $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'authRedirect'], 1000);
    }
}
```

The `checkPermission` method just checks if the user role and the matched route are in the acl storage.
If this fails I will redirect a status code of 404.

**Problem**: The unit test fails: "Failed asserting response code "200", actual status code is "302"
Therefore the unit test jumps into the else case from my `onBootstrap` method in the `Module.php` where the redirect happen.

I did the following `setUp` in the *TestCase* but it doesn't work:

```
public function setUp()
{
    // override default configuration values
    $configOverrides = [];

    $this->setApplicationConfig(ArrayUtils::merge(
        include __DIR__ . '/../../../../config/application.config.php',
        $configOverrides
    ));

    $user = new Employee();
    $user->id = 1;
    $user->system_name = 'admin';
    $user->role = 'Admin';

    $this->authService = $this->prophesize(AuthService::class);
    $auth = $this->prophesize(AuthenticationService::class);
    $auth->hasIdentity()->willReturn(true);
    $auth->getIdentity()->willReturn($user);

    $this->authService->getAuth()->willReturn($auth->reveal());

    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setService(AuthService::class, $this->authService->reveal());
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(false);

    parent::setUp();
}
```

> Hints are very appreciated

The code might differ a bit from *Zend Framework 2* but If you have a simple working example in zf2 maybe I can transform it into zf3 style.

I don't use ZfcUser - just the zend-acl / zend-authentication stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several days of headache I've got a working solution.

First I moved all the code within the `onBootstrap` to a Listener, because the phpunit mocks are generated after the zf bootstrapping and therefore are non existent in my unit tests.

The key is, that the services are generated in my callable listener method, which is called after zf finished bootstrapping.
Then PHPUnit can override the service with the provided mock.

`AuthenticationListener`

```
class AuthenticationListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
use ListenerAggregateTrait;

/**
 * @var AuthenticationService
 */
private $auth;

/**
 * @var Acl
 */
private $acl;

/**
 * Attach one or more listeners
 *
 * Implementors may add an optional $priority argument; the EventManager
 * implementation will pass this to the aggregate.
 *
 * @param EventManagerInterface $events
 * @param int $priority
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
{
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, [$this, 'checkAuthentication']);
}

/**
 * @param MvcEvent $event
 */
public function checkAuthentication($event)
{
    $this->auth = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(AuthenticationService::class);
    $aclService = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(AclService::class);
    $this->acl = $aclService->init();

    $event->getViewModel()->setVariable('acl', $this->acl);
    if ($this->auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $this->checkPermission($event);
    } else {
        $this->authRedirect($event);
    }
}

// checkPermission & authRedirect method
}
```

Now my `onBootstrap` got really small, just like ZF wants it. [documentation reference](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-modulemanager/best-practices/#keep-the-init-and-onbootstrap-methods-lightweight)

`Module.php`

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $authListener = new AuthenticationListener();
    $authListener->attach($event->getApplication()->getEventManager());
}
```

Finally my mocking in the unit test looks like this:

`IndexControllerTest`

```
private function authMock()
{
    $mockAuth = $this->getMockBuilder(AuthenticationService::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $mockAuth->expects($this->any())->method('hasIdentity')->willReturn(true);
    $mockAuth->expects($this->any())->method('getIdentity')->willReturn(['id' => 1, 'systemName' => 'admin', 'role' => 'Admin']);

    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setService(AuthenticationService::class, $mockAuth);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(false);
}
```

Comment: I have tried you solution but I am getting error `Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService`