# zf3 unit testing: getHeaders not accessible in onBootstrap

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am using `Module.php` `onBootstrap`function to check using authentication. on Postman and with browser everything works fine but when unittesting with `zend-test` it is not able to access the `getHeaders()` 
MY `Module.php`

```
     public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
      {
        $app = $e->getTarget();
        $locator = $app->getServiceManager();
        $this->authorize($e);
      }

      public function authorize($e){
        $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $request = $sm->get('Request');

       if($request->getHeaders('auth_token')){
            return;
        }
        $response = $e->getResponse();
    $model = new JsonModel(array(
        "httpStatus" => 401,
        "title" => "Token Not Found",
    ));
    $e->getResponse()->setStatusCode(401);
    $model->detail = "Auth Token not provided";

    $model->setTerminal(true);
    $e->setResult($model);
    $e->setViewModel($model);
}
```

Now i tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075255/zf3-unit-test-authentication-onbootstrap) but i couldn't because the code is so difficult to follow.

My test is something like that:

```
public function testIndexIsAccessibleAction() {
    $headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
    $headers->addHeaders([
        "auth_token" => 'token' 
    ]);
    $this->getRequest()
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->getHeaders()
            ->addHeaders($headers);
         ;
    $this->dispatch('/action');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
}
```

Now i am checking every request in `onBootstrap` because nothing is accessible if user is not authentic. How do i do my unit testing correctly. and how should i change it to using `Service` or `Factory`?

Comment: What does `getRequest` of your test class return?

Comment: It doesn't return the keys and values i passed to it

Comment: I changed the `this->authorize($e)`with `$events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'authorize'));` and it is working now

Comment: But i think adding this in bootstrap in not a good practice so...

Comment: When it comes to Authentication and Authorization I would suggest you either grab an existing service (github vendor module) or you create your own module with your own services to handle this. To give you a leg up, you could have a look at an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261931/zf3-dependency-injection-in-module-php/52265276#52265276) of mine on a similar question. Using separate classes should also make them easier to mock/test.